# How to parse data from API response when dynamic key? (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, parsing

How can this data be parsed when key is value itself or dynamic not static. Below is the api response JSON format:

```
"result": {
    "23-05-2019": [
        {
            "date": "23-05-2019",
            "time": "10:00"
        },
        {
            "date": "23-05-2019",
            "time": "12:30"
        },
        {
            "date": "23-05-2019",
            "time": "17:00"
        }
    ],
    "25-05-2019": [
        {
            "date": "25-05-2019",
            "time": "11:00"
        },
        {
            "date": "25-05-2019",
            "time": "09:30"
        },
        {
            "date": "25-05-2019",
            "time": "05:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

In above response, result contains  "23-05-2019" as key through which i need to access the array. Please guide.

Comment: My question is strictly for objective c

Comment: Parse it into what? It's just NSDictionary, NSArray, NSString once JSON converted in Objective-C objects. What do you want in the end?